# Connect Python script to PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, odbc

Hey I'm not sure what is wrong with this connection string, i'm getting the error - pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

here is my script:

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = (
    "DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};"
    "DATABASE=postgres;"
    "UID=postgres;"
    "PWD=password;"
    "SERVER=localhost;"
    "PORT=5432;"
    )
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM initialdata limit 50")
row = crsr.fetchone()
print(row)
crsr.close()
conn.close()
```

and here is my ODBCINST.INI file contents:

```
[PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) (32 bit)]
Driver=C:\Program Files\psqlODBC\0905\bin\psqlodbc30a.dll
Setup=C:\Program Files\psqlODBC\0905\bin\psqlodbc30a.dll
32Bit=1

[ODBC 32 bit Drivers]
PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) (32 bit)=Installed
PostgreSQL Unicode(x64) (32 bit)=Installed

[PostgreSQL Unicode(x64) (32 bit)]
Driver=C:\Program Files\psqlODBC\0905\bin\psqlodbc35w.dll
Setup=C:\Program Files\psqlODBC\0905\bin\psqlodbc35w.dll
32Bit=1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Based on the odbcinst.ini file it looks like your driver name should be: PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) (32 bit) ... not just PostgreSQL ANSI

Comment: What does the name look like in your ODBC Data Source Administrator (odbcad32.exe), Drivers tab.  Also... it looks like you're running 32bit drivers on a 64bit machine.  Is your python 32 or 64 bit?  It should match the drivers that you installed.

Answer (score 4):

check list of drivers by using `pyodbc.drivers()` and use driver name from it

the driver name should be like `PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)` instead of `PostgreSQL ANSI`.